# eclipse run/debug launch configs in ws/.../.launch do not show up in config dialog

Tags: eclipse, configuration, launch

regardless of importing them via file/import or just copy them from an old workspace to a new one (.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches) they didn't appear in the eclipse run/debug configurations dialog.

(however if i try to import them *after* i copied them already to that folder, i'm asked to override them - so that directory seems to be the correct one...)

**my question is**: how do i (re)import elder run/debug configurations to a new eclipse workspace?

**update**
[this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.100953_0527_00_en/mey1476794626372.html) doesn't work out form me with versions 1903, 1909 and 1912

Comment: If exporting and importing does not work for you, maybe the new version cannot read the old ones. Share an old and a new launch configuration (see my answer below how to share launch configurations) and compare them to see what have changed. About what kind of launch configuration and about what Eclipse version do you talk (1903, 1909 and 1912 are not Eclipse versions; see _Help > About..._)?

Comment: i did compared them already without a clue - nevertheless i was't aware of the version-thing, thx - i'll remember next time. for now, see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Do one of the following:

- **Export and import** the launch configurations:

  1. In the old workspace do ***File > Export...: Run/Debug > Launch Configurations***
  2. In the new workspace do ***File > Import...: Run/Debug > Launch Configurations***
- **Share** launch configurations:

  1. In the old workspace in ***Run > Run Configurations...*** in the ***Common*** tab of all launch configurations to share select for ***Save as*** the option ***Shared file***
  2. **Copy the `<name>.launch`** file into a project of the new workspace

Please be aware that the files in `.metadata` are not intended to be edited or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

thx @howlger for the approach - it was my fault and a silly mistake.
(i put this in here for the next luser like me XD)

- the problem was, that the ones (the configs) I've missed did't show up, because the projects for this configs were not open in my new workspace. thats all.

when opening them, the configs will be listed in the overview.

Comment: In the _Run/Debug Configurations_ dialog in the menu on the top left there is the option _Filter Closed Projects_ which is enabled by default.